SKBitmap resourceID = SKBitmap.Decode(stream); is throwing a System.ArgumentNullException:
SKBitmap resourceID = SKBitmap.Decode(stream); is throwing a System.ArgumentNullException.
I tried changing the names, but it's not working. I can't understand what the error is. Please tell me. Here's a photo and the path:
"C:\Users\user\source\repos\надіюся хоч щось виде ,_,\надіюся хоч щось виде ,,\textures\character\барикада горизонталь.png".

[
Tried to change the name of the reference to the object and refer through the change and directly in the GetManifestResourceStream() method through double quotes.
Also tried moving images to different folders in the middle of the project and even without them.
